# Best way to publish dynamic content in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I have this scenario where an external service provides information I want to display as content on the site. I can inject the service interface in the content handler but I'm stuck there. Lets say the service has a method that returns an array of items:

```
 MemberInfo[] GetMembers();
```

If I model MemberInfo as a content part I am unable to add(build new parts) dynamicaly at the handler? Is this because a content type can only have one instance of a content part? What's the best way for Orchard to model such thing then? Should I just pass MemberInfo[] to the driver/shape/views and render them without it being a content part/field/type? It works but if I want to reuse MemberInfo and have some behaviour on it(with its handler etc...) it doesn't sound optimal.

Is there a way to dynamically build "MemberInfoPart"s and attach them onto a content item(not type, since different items can display different members)?

Second one that comes to mind is to model MemberInfo as a content type and then use Container parts or projections. This way information from the service(not just MemberInfo[]) would become a set of content items. But where to build it? In what Content handler or else?

Comment: It looks like you're making it way more complicated than it needs to be. You can have a custom part with complex properties, including an array type.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy That was my first atempt, and I filled up the array in the content handler. It works but if I want MemberInfo to be a content type/part and reuse it in various other content types? It is basically a 1:N relation without it being stored in the db.

Comment: So what difference does it make?

Comment: None actually, my intent was to model MemberInfo as a separate entity from the encapsulating content type. I guess there are just too many ways to do this in Orchard and I'm new to it ;) I've thought of content types per entity and then "link" them by projections etc... But I'll probably go with one custom part(or type) as it is the most simple for me at the moment. Thanks.